# How can I disable update table for all user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a table that I want no one to update, in other words I want to disable updates on this table. For this purpose I know two methods, first is to use `instead of update` trigger to prevent update and second is to use permissions.

I want to figure out best practices for this purpose.

EDIT 1:
   I want to deny update for all user.

Comment: Why, oh why, would you use trigger to simulate something that SQL Server offers you for free?

Comment: Some time administrator forget that table was not updatable. When I use trigger no one can update this table. of course administrator can disable trigger but disable trigger is with awareness.

Comment: So you try to fix an organizational problem introducing a technical one?

Comment: Some time, data is very important and never must change these. even by Administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, using permissions to disable updates to a table is probably the best way to go.

EDIT: [Check Giving and removing permissions in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I Know that Instead of update is for redirecting but I can raised error in Instead of trigger for each update.

Comment: How I can deny update permission for all user (deny permission each by each use or can deny for all).

Comment: You can use something on the following line `DENY UPDATE on SCHEMA::table TO user`

Comment: @Habib.OSU, I don't get it. Can more help me. I want to `DENY UPDATE for all user` no `DENY UPDATE on all table to single user`

Comment: @Habib.OSU I check above link. but I want to deny permission for all user. in your link, when I define new user, must be deny update permission for new defined user. and may be forget it.

Comment: @mehdilotfi, it that particular case, I am not sure if you can deny update for all users, you may use instead of update trigger.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, SQL  the `i-am-a-dummy` flag makes the MySQL, SQL engine deny the `UPDATE and DELETE` commands unless the `WHERE` clause is present.