# Effectively make database records read-only

Tags: sql, t-sql, readonly, records

How can I make sure that specific data in the database isn't altered anymore.

We are working with TSQL. Inside the database we store contract revisions. These have a status: draft / active. When the status has become active, the revision may never be altered anymore. A revision can have 8 active modules (each with its own table), each with their own settings and sub-tables. This creates a whole tree of tables with records that may never change anymore when the contract revision has been set to active.

Ideally I would simply mark those records as read-only. But such thing does not exists as of today. The next thing that comes to mind are triggers. Thus I have to add those triggers to a lot of tables, all which are related to the contract revision.

Now maybe there are other approaches, like a database only for archiving on which the user only has insert rights. Thus when a contract revision has become active, it is moved from one DB to the archive DB (insert is allowed). And can never be altered anymore (DENY UPDATE|DELETE).

But maybe there are other more ingenious options I haven't thought of, and you did. Maybe including the CLR or what not.

So how can I make a tree-structure of records inside our TSQL database effectively readonly that is the most maintenance free, easy to understand, quickly to setup, and can be applied in a most generic way?

Comment: restrict users abilites to actually effect changes. Make the users who have access to said tables only have permissions to insert, not delete or update.

Comment: Maybe this question can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185932/how-can-i-disable-update-table-for-all-user

Comment: @Takarii Thank you for your comment. This is however not solvig the problem as we also want to prevent bugs in stored procedues and EF to not being able to accidentally alter or delete the data. Imagine faulty joins in an UPDATE statement. There is quiet a lot of code spread in SQL and C# that does something to a contract revision or one of its modules.

Comment: @JoeTaras Thank you for your comment. This would not solve the problem has a contract revision may be updated, as longs as its status is Draft. When it set to have the status Active, it must become effectively readonly.

Answer (score 1):

What ever you do (triggers, granted rights...) might be overcome by a user with higher rights, this you know for sure...

Is this just to archive this data?

One idea coming into my mind was to create a nested XML with all data within on big structure and put this somewhere into a side table. Create a `INSTEAD OF UPDATE,DELETE TRIGGER` where you just do nothing. Let these tables be `1:1`-related.

You can still work with this data, but not quite as fast as being read from physical tables.

If you want, you even might convert the XML to a string and calculate some Hash-Code, which you store in a different place to check for manipulations.

The whole process might be done in one single Stored Procedure call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Storing hashes can atleast flag errors. Great idea! I am going to look into that XML. Many thanks.